# C# How to Save multiple rows from Datagridview to One Database

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I have 2 datagridview and need to save them in one database.

I don't know how to explain this, but here I link the video I made directly from my desktop.

[Youtube video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j_c3SiAfmwg&feature=youtu.be)

And here my Save Button code for this form.

```
{
    public Invoices()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    MySqlConnection Connection = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost; database=lmsdb; user=root; password=; pooling = false; convert zero datetime=True");
    //MySqlConnection Connection = new MySqlConnection("server=35.186.146.59;database=lmsdb;uid=lmsdb;pwd=dbserver; pooling = false; convert zero datetime=True");
    BindingSource bsInvoices = new BindingSource();


    private void Invoices_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindGrid();
    }

    private void BindGrid()
    {
        MySqlConnection Connection = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost; database=lmsdb; user=root; password=; pooling = false; convert zero datetime=True");
        //Connection.Open();

        MySqlCommand Command = new MySqlCommand("Select * From invoicesdb", Connection);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(Command);

        da.Fill(dt);
        dgvInvoiceList.DataSource = null;
        dgvInvoiceList.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        dgvInvoiceList.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dgvInvoiceList.ColumnCount = 16;
        dgvInvoiceList.Columns[0].HeaderText = "ID";
        dgvInvoiceList.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "id";
        dgvInvoiceList.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Client Name";
        dgvInvoiceList.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "ClientName";
        dgvInvoiceList.Columns[2].HeaderText = "References No";
        dgvInvoiceList.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "ReferencesNo";
        dgvInvoiceList.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Case No";
        dgvInvoiceList.Columns[3].DataPropertyName = "CaseNo";
        dgvInvoiceList.Columns[4].HeaderText = "NRIC No";
        dgvInvoiceList.Columns[4].DataPropertyName = "NRICNo";
        dgvInvoiceList.Columns[5].HeaderText = "GST No";
        dgvInvoiceList.Columns[5].DataPropertyName = "GSTNo";
        dgvInvoiceList.Columns[6].HeaderText = "Invoices Date";
        dgvInvoiceList.Columns[6].DataPropertyName = "InvoicesDate";
        dgvInvoiceList.Columns[7].HeaderText = "Invoices Tax No";
        dgvInvoiceList.Columns[7].DataPropertyName = "InvoicesTaxNo";
        dgvInvoiceList.Columns[8].HeaderText = "Issue Date";
        dgvInvoiceList.Columns[8].DataPropertyName = "IssueDate";
        dgvInvoiceList.Columns[9].HeaderText = "Due Date";
        dgvInvoiceList.Columns[9].DataPropertyName = "DueDate";
        dgvInvoiceList.Columns[10].HeaderText = "Legal Fees";
        dgvInvoiceList.Columns[10].DataPropertyName = "LegalFees";
        dgvInvoiceList.Columns[11].HeaderText = "Stage";
        dgvInvoiceList.Columns[11].DataPropertyName = "StageSchedule";
        dgvInvoiceList.Columns[12].HeaderText = "Description";
        dgvInvoiceList.Columns[12].DataPropertyName = "Description";
        dgvInvoiceList.Columns[13].HeaderText = "Legal Fees Total";
        dgvInvoiceList.Columns[13].DataPropertyName = "LegalFeesTotal";
        dgvInvoiceList.Columns[14].HeaderText = "Disbursement Total";
        dgvInvoiceList.Columns[14].DataPropertyName = "DisbursementTotal";
        dgvInvoiceList.Columns[15].HeaderText = "Grand Total";
        dgvInvoiceList.Columns[15].DataPropertyName = "GrandTotal";
        dgvInvoiceList.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        dgvInvoiceList.DataSource = dt;
        Connection.Close();

        MySqlConnection Connection2 = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost; database=lmsdb; user=root; password=; pooling = false; convert zero datetime=True");
        //Connection.Open();

        MySqlCommand Command2 = new MySqlCommand("Select * From invoicesdb", Connection2);
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
        MySqlDataAdapter da2 = new MySqlDataAdapter(Command2);

        da2.Fill(dt2);
        dgvDisList.DataSource = null;
        dgvDisList.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        dgvDisList.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dgvDisList.ColumnCount = 2;
        dgvDisList.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Description";
        dgvDisList.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "DisbursementDescription";
        dgvDisList.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Amount";
        dgvDisList.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "DisbursementAmount";
        dgvDisList.DataSource = dt2;
        Connection2.Close();

    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MySqlConnection Connection = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost; database=lmsdb; user=root; password=; pooling = false; convert zero datetime=True");

        for (int i = 0; i < dgvDisList.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string disDescription = dgvDisList.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            string disAmount = dgvDisList.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand($"INSERT INTO invoicesdb (id, ClientName, ReferencesNo, CaseNo, NRICNo, GSTNo, InvoicesDate, InvoicesTaxNo, IssueDate, DueDate, LegalFees, StageSchedule, Description, DisbursementDescription, DisbursementAmount, LegalFeesTotal, DisbursementTotal, GrandTotal) Values ('{tbID.Text}', {tbClientName.Text}','{tbReferencesNo.Text}','{tbCaseNo.Text}','{tbNRICNo.Text}','{tbGST.Text}','{dateInvoice.Text}','{tbInvoiceTaxNo.Text}','{dateIssue.Text}','{dateDue.Text}', '{tbLegalFees.Text}','{cbStageSchedule.Text}','{tbDescription.Text}','{ disDescription }','{ disAmount }','{tbTotalLegalFees.Text}','{tbTotalDisbursement.Text}','{tbGrandTotal.Text}')", Connection);

            Connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Connection.Close();
        }

        Invoices_Load(sender, e);
        MessageBox.Show("Saved Successfully");
        btnNew_Click(sender, e);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: A video explaining your issue is not sufficient here - please add a description in text form in the question itself.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I'm having problem at Insert (Save) part. Since you see the video, on my first DGV, I put 2 temporary values before save it to the database then when I click save button, the data from my 2nd DGV become two, that because I got 2 temporary valueson my first DGV. How can I save multiple rows datagridview and save it into one database?

Comment: Sorry, I think I understand and sorry for the title, what I need is, how can I save all rows of datagridview into one ID database?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to import the following namespaces.

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Inside the Form Load event, the DataGridView is populated with a dynamic DataTable

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 this.BindDataGridView();
}

private void BindDataGridView()
{
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.AddRange(new .....
```

a loop is executed over the DataGridView rows. Inside the loop, the values from each column (cell) of the DataGridView are fetched and the record is inserted into the database table.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I try your method, but need some confirmation, do I have to delete my BindGrid code and put new code as you refer above?

Comment: structure your code according to the code and loop like this for example..

    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
   cmdd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Char, 20, "Id").Value = row.Cells[0].Value;

Comment: Hi, I already test this code, still the same and I'm so sorry, I think I made a mistake here. What I need is, how can I save all the rows from datagridview to the one ID database.